# How can I make the sign appear at the end of the fill when using std::cout and std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, std, cout, stringstream

I have the following code for formatting a printout to always be 4 digits with sign included:

```
std::stringstream pitch; 
pitch.precision(0);

pitch.width(4);
pitch.fill('0');

pitch << std::showpos << (int)(m_values["Pitch_1"]);
```

I would also like to show the sign ("+"/"-"), but I want it to precede the fill, as follows:

```
+002
```

However, the code I have here moves the "+" sign to the most significant digit:

```
00+2
```

How, if possible, can I change the formatting so that I have the former, instead of the latter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `std::internal` manipulator:

```
pitch << std::internal << std::showpos << 5;
```